# Understanding Docker best practices

Tags: docker

I understand that Docker is a whole new world of possibilities which are well presented around the web, but with these new options come new risks which I'm wondering about. Best practices to work around these risks are one thing experience brings, but since I lack the experience on the subject...

Here are the few aspects of an application dockerization which present risks depending on the implementation choices:

**1. Image specialization and industrialization**

I understand that a running Docker application means 2 parts:

- Invariable part: the Docker Image
- Variable part: all the user-added files and meta-data

My question is: what is the right way to specialize my image for a specific deployment (customer, environment, configuration)? Where to store the variable part for ensuring more evolutivity and segregation/security?

**2. Application lifecycle management**

Let's say I develop the Docker image of MyApplication

- At some point I deploy v1 which is going to live for some time with specific user-added files and meta-data stored into my Docker Container
- At some point I completed v2 development and I want to update my existing v1

What are the right procedure/design/practices to ensure a clean and easy migration considering that

- my image v2 might require more parameters than my v1
- I want all my user-added files or meta-data to remain

**3.  Multiple Container communication and security**

I want to setup a multi-container deployment with secured inter-container communication.

- What is the right way to handle network flows between all these containers?
- Since I want to setup x509 certificates, CN have to match hostnames... How to handle for all these containers?
- Can Docker handle some kind of VLAN to define security layers between several groups of containers?

Thanks!

Comment: for `Can Docker handle some kind of VLAN to define security layers between several groups of containers?` see https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_create/ and https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/dockernetworks/

Comment: and the answer of VonC http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35314092/docker-refer-to-registry-by-ip-address

Comment: This question is difficult to answer - it's not one question, and it's really quite broad/opinion based. Please see [ask] as to what makes a good question. I would suggest narrowing down one specific question, and asking that - trying to keep away from the opinion based answers.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. In my opinion, there is many ways to get to a result, but there is not that many options which gather most pro and less cons. If not here, I'm going to find the answers somewhere at some point, and I'll provide them. As for 1st point, I think that I now have the answer: data volumes in containers. Not sure yet about 2nd point, but I'm gonna dig into networking features from Docker-compose for 3rd point.