# Docker: Refer to registry by ip address

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I have a Docker image I want to push to my registry (hosted on `localhost`). I do:

```
docker push localhost:5000/my_image
```

and works properly. However, if I tag the image and push it by:

```
docker push 172.20.20.20:5000/my_image
```

I get an error.

> `The push refers to a repository [172.20.20.20:5000/my_tomcat] (len: 1)`
>   `unable to ping registry endpoint https://172.20.20.20:5000/v0/ v2`
>   `ping attempt failed with error:
>
>     Get https://172.20.20.20:5000/v2/: Gateway Time-out`

Can't I refer to registry by IP? If so, how could I push an image from another host that it is not `localhost`?

**EDIT**

I'm running the registry this way:

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry registry:2
```

Comment: To me that suggests the service is bound to a local IP (127.0.0.1) and therefore won't respond on the other. How are you specifying the IP which the registry listens on?

Comment: I have edited the question. Basically, I use `-p` option for the port but I do nothing about IPs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in "[IPs for all the Things](https://blog.jessfraz.com/post/ips-for-all-the-things/)" (by [Jess Frazelle](https://github.com/jfrazelle)), you should be able, with docker 1.10, to run your registry with a fixed IP address.

It uses the [`--net= --ip=` options of docker run](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#connect-a-container-to-a-network-net).

```
# create a new bridge network with your subnet and gateway for your ip block
$ docker network create --subnet 203.0.113.0/24 --gateway 203.0.113.254 iptastic

# run a nginx container with a specific ip in that block
$ docker run --rm -it --net iptastic --ip 203.0.113.2 nginx

# curl the ip from any other place (assuming this is a public ip block duh)
$ curl 203.0.113.2
```

You can adapt this example to your registry docker run parameters.

Answer (score 2):

First of all please check whether you are able to connect the registry on the port 5000. In Linux/windows you can do this using telnet. below is the command.

$ telnet 172.20.20.20 5000

If the connectivity check is failed then please check your firewall settings.

I am not sure whether you are running your running registry with login functionality. But from the question i can assume that you are not using it. In this case please add your registry as an insecure registry in the docker daemon from which you are trying to access the registry. The process is described here - https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/

Please let me know if are successful.